# Howto take a glimpse into mscorlib?

Tags: c#, cryptoapi, mscorlib

I want to read data into RSAParameters structure ( [RSAParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ) and did check twice, that the data is correct. But still, I get an error "invalid data" exception for this:

```
   bei System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   bei System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP, Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
   bei System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
```

How can I take a look into the source code to check why _ImportKeys is throwing an exception? I have no experience with .dll 'decryption'..are there any symbols to reference somewhere for visual studio 8.0? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble the DLL you want to examine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/). It is 100% free.