# Serialization throwing ArgumentException / InvalidCastException: debug approach needed

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization, asp.net-3.5, dotnetnuke

We have a web solution with mixed C# and VB.NET (3.5) projects (note: several vb.net files do have Option Strict Off). Our code runs as modules inside DotNetNuke 4.8. Under certain conditions, our application will crash at the method:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteString
```

The abbreviated message in that exception is:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Error serializing value XYZ of type XYZ."
System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' 
to 'System.String'"
```

Nowhere in the stack trace is our code, it's just System code that ends up failing to serialize type `XYZ` from our code. This means I can't hit a break point and debug which exact property of XYZ is the problem. The stack trace property is empty, but in the Message is a stack trace abbreviated as:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: "Error serializing value 'XYZ' of type 'XYZ.'" 
  System.ArgumentException: "Error serializing value 'XYZ' of type 'XYZ.'" 
  System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'. "
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteString(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object stringObject)
// ...... etc.........
at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
// --- End of inner exception stack trace
```

All relevant lines in this trace start with `System.`. The top lines are DotNetNuke. However, following the first answer's suggestion I compiled the DotNetNuke (4.8) code myself and turns out that code just does `Server.GetLastError`, showing the InvalidCastException as the InnerException without any additional info on the actual value or property name being serialized.

**The question then is**: how do I discover which field and value the serializer is having trouble with?

A few related questions/problems that came to mind while researching this problem:

- If I look at the [Formatters.Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1y2tet%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) part of MSDN I'd guess the ObjectWriter is internal for Binary (as suggested in the comments, red)?
- How can .NET even at all fail at casting a Int64 to String? Rephrased: what value for a Int64 could potentially not be converted to a String? However, as pointed out in comments: Int64 can easily be converted to Strings, but Casting them is a different issue.
- The [Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method doesn't announce this ArgumentException or InvalidCastException may occur (in the Exceptions section).

I tried investigating `XYZ` and types for properties in that class in ildasm to see any irregularities but couldn't find any.

Comment: `(string)42L` throws an InvalidCastException, and so does any other Int64 value. Int64 values cannot be casted to `string`. (You can **convert**  it to `string` using `Convert.ToString(42L)` or `42L.ToString()` though.)

Comment: `ObjectWriter` is an `internal` class in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` namespace.

Comment: Ah thank you for both the helpful comments! Makes sense. Think I'll update the question on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, hopefully that will help anyone ending up here after a search query.

The final answer was found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943854/howto-take-a-glimpse-into-mscorlib). I ended up using a trial version of the .NET Reflector (and the included Visual Studio 2010 plugin) to step into the mscorlib code. This allowed me to inspect the NameInfo for the property that was causing the InvalidCastException.

In short, the answer was: use .NET Reflector (or a similar tool) to step into mscorlib.

---

PS. While stepping into mscorlib was the answer to my problem posed in this question, there's still an underlying problem which probably warrants a whole new SO question, once I grab enough info on it.

Comment: If it's in the DNN Framework, don't forget to log it in Gemini, even if the answer is to catch and report the invalid cast better.

Comment: I would, but in the end I don't think DNN had anything to do with it, except for noticing the problem with `Server.GetLastError`. If I do find anything on this I will though. Thanks for all the tips and feedback in this Question :D

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what the stack trace was - although that might not be relevant.

If it's in the DotNetNuke code, I would load the DotNetNuke source up into your debugger, and recreate the exception.  You might also get away with compiling the (relevant version) DotNetNuke source and just dropping the newly-compiled dll and .pdb files into your \bin directory.

Once you've got that set up, go into Visual Studio -> Debug, Exceptions, and put a checkbox next to 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' in the 'Thrown' column.  You might also experiment with 'Native Run-Time checks'.

Then recreate your test.  The code should break at the point the exception is thrown.  When this happens you'll be able to inspect not only the stack trace of how you got to that point, you should be able to determine the value that is causing the problem.

Note that using this approach you'll come across a lot of other exceptions - there are places where try/catch is used as a way of handling code, and these will all show up.  You'll just have step through these examples until you find the one you need.

If all else fails I would recompile with a 'try/catch' in it and log/break on the offending values, but you shouldn't need to go that far.  Just having Visual Studio break on the thrown error should be enough to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will certainly give this a go when I have the time and update the Q and/or accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but not the answer to my problem unfortunately. When I hit the breakpoint in DotNetNuke it turns out it's just handling `Server.GetLastError`, and at that point the InnerException (the `InvalidCastException`) doesn't provide any info on the actual value (or property) serialization failed on.

Comment: I know you've solved the error now, but when this happens I go nuclear and enable every single debugging option hoping to catch it.  This ends up in an unimaginably high amount of exception noise to sort through, but generally with persistence the right one comes up.  But sounds like you figured it out anyway.

Comment: Going nuclear certainly seems an option, though in this particular case .NET Reflector and checking the "Thrown" option for InvalidCastException only was enough :)